# weird swift issue when defining class (segmentation 11)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, segmentation-fault

so i am trying to define a swift class that will work in both swift and objective-c.

When i try this way

```
    import Foundation

        @objc class TestClass
        {

            private var m_FirstName : String
            private var m_LastName  : String
            private var m_Id : String

        init()
        {

            m_FirstName = ""
            m_LastName = ""
            m_Id = "userIdNotSet-badescuga"
            }

         init(firstName:String, lastName:String, id:String)
            {
                m_FirstName = firstName
                m_LastName = lastName
                    m_Id = id
                }
        }
```

i get a weird error:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

which is somewhat understandable because i don't have a `String` class in objective-c. But even if i change all the `String` class objects to `NSString` i still get the same error.

What am i doing wrong?? I using Xcode 6.1.1 and i've also tried it on xcode 6.2.3 Beta

**UPDATE**

I also tried inheriting from the NSObject class with the same result: i get the same error

**UPDATE 2**

I get the error when i'm trying to compile the project. I am not using this class in any way. It is just for test purposes.

Comment: Do you have `import Foundation` anywhere? Also, if it doesn't defeat some other purpose that you have in mind, try having the class inherit from `NSObject`: `class TestObject: NSObject...`

Comment: yes, i import Foundation.. And i've also tried inheriting from NSObject with no luck: I get the same error.

Comment: This is not full code. Show how you use `TestClass`.

Comment: *When* does it fail?

Comment: The class fails on compile @SebastianDressler.

Comment: The class is just for testing, i'm not using it in any way @WojtekSurowka

Comment: Class compiles fine in latest 6.2beta4 - in fact I added the class to a project, then instantiated two objects: let f1: TestClass = TestClass()
 let f2: TestClass = TestClass(firstName: "Barney", lastName: "Phife", id: "4135")

Comment: @DavidH i've tested it also on http://swiftstub.com/775615856/ and it looks that it works ok. The problem must be somewhere else (but related to this class declaration) :-?

Comment: Start commenting out chunks of your code until you can narrow it down.

Comment: I found the same problem when you try to add Swift Unit Tests to an application that has a mix Swift/Objective-C code, after loosing the fight I just rewrite the Unit Tests in Objective-C and everything worked now.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to your stored properties being marked with **private** access. Swift compiler doesn't add *@objc* automatically to those marked as **private** (since it's assumed internal use).

Try prepending *@objc* before each private properties and see how it goes.

Also if a class inherits NSObject there's no need for explicit @objc tag.

Comment: That was not the issue. From what i can see, the compiler really doesn't like passing NSString or String as init parameters. I kind of resolved the problem by changing the parameters types to AnyObject when i pass them and converting them to their specific type in the constructor.. but is far from ideal. Data is not type-safe. @pie-o-pah

Comment: also, i saw that not declaring the variables with "?", makes it crash in some cases.. weird stuff.. can't wait for a swift update. @pie-o-pah

Comment: That wasn't a bug. You need to pre-declare a variable as optional (can contain `nil` value) up front if you think it is likely to hold it at some point. `?` is used for optional variable, while `!` is used to explicitly unwrap it. I do think this feature is in fact the elegant part of Swift.

Comment: I am talking about using the swift class in obj-c. What i am saying is that,  in some cases, not declaring a variable as optional and declaring the class usable in obj-c led to segmentation errors (in some cases, is others not). This is clearly a current dev platform bug. Segmentation errors shouldn't be shown in such a case. of course ?/! aren't a bug in swift, lol :)) @pie-o-pah